# Is there a way to know that user changed his video with youtube video editor(add annotations, change audio, etc...)?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

What fields i need to save and then check them through API?

Is there any solution to do this?
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

But you can try:

## [Activities](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities)

> An `activity` resource contains information about an action that a particular channel, or user, has taken on YouTube. The actions reported in activity feeds include *rating a video, sharing a video, marking a video as a favorite, uploading a video, and so forth*. Each `activity` resource identifies the type of action, the channel associated with the action, and the resource(s) associated with the action, such as the video that was rated or uploaded.

It is not really specific about changes in Youtube video but activities regarding channels and users (rating a video, sharing a video, marking a video as a favorite, uploading a video, and so forth)